# S3 get operation only one time?

Tags: amazon-s3

Is there any way of allowing only 1 get operation for an S3 file, then have it deleted automatically?

My current implementation depends on a server for downloading from S3 and providing the file to the user, which works but it ends up being a bottleneck when there are too many users...

I am very interested in allowing only 1 get operation for an S3 file, maybe with some kind of policy?

I did some search but found nothing :f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there is no way (or at least I haven't heard of any) to have such restriction on Amazon S3 servers. But such function could be implemented on you client side.